# systemd --user unit, mapp .img as loop device

Tags: permissions, systemd, loop-device

I want to use a `systemd --user .service` to map an image file to a loop device at user login. The the service resides in `/etc/systemd/user`. The image in question resides in /home/$USER/my.img

```
[Unit]
Description=Setup loop device

[Service]

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/losetup /dev/loop0 /home/john/my.img

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The unit fails with

```
losetup: /dev/loop1: failed to set up loop device: Permission denied
```

I understand `losetup` can not be called by a user. Placing the unit in `/etc/systemd/system` works, but accessing the file prompts the sudo password, witch i want to avoid.

How should i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

From https://giorgos.sealabs.net/systemd-unit-to-activate-loopback-devices-before-lvm.html

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Activate loop device
 DefaultDependencies=no
 After=systemd-udev-settle.service
 Before=lvm2-activation-early.service
 Wants=systemd-udev-settle.service

 [Service]
 ExecStart=/sbin/losetup /dev/loop0 /volume.img
 Type=oneshot 

 [Install]
 WantedBy=local-fs.target
```